# I found Error " E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout "

Tags: android

Everything works, but after I check the log it shows:

> "E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout ".

My home fragment code:

```
package com.apps.mathar;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.apps.adapter.AdapterRecent;
import com.apps.item.ItemSong;
import com.apps.utils.Constant;
import com.apps.utils.DBHelper;
import com.apps.utils.JsonUtils;
import com.apps.utils.RecyclerItemClickListener;
import com.apps.utils.ZProgressHUD;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Callback;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FragmentHome extends Fragment {

    DBHelper dbHelper;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<ItemSong> arrayList;
    ArrayList<ItemSong> arrayList_recent;
    AdapterRecent adapterRecent;
    ZProgressHUD progressHUD;
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    public ViewPager viewpager;
    ImagePagerAdapter adapter;
    TextView textView_empty;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(getActivity());

        progressHUD = ZProgressHUD.getInstance(getActivity());
        progressHUD.setMessage(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.loading));
        progressHUD.setSpinnerType(ZProgressHUD.FADED_ROUND_SPINNER);

        textView_empty = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView_recent_empty);

        adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
        viewpager = (ViewPager)rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewPager_home);
        viewpager.setPadding(80,20,80,20);
        viewpager.setClipToPadding(false);
        viewpager.setPageMargin(40);
        viewpager.setClipChildren(false);
//        viewpager.setPageTransformer(true,new BackgroundToForegroundTransformer());

        arrayList = new ArrayList<ItemSong>();
        arrayList_recent = new ArrayList<ItemSong>();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_home_recent);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        if (JsonUtils.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())) {
            new LoadLatestNews().execute(Constant.URL_LATEST);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.internet_not_conn), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                if(JsonUtils.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())) {
                    Constant.isOnline = true;
                    Constant.arrayList_play.clear();
                    Constant.arrayList_play.addAll(arrayList_recent);
                    Constant.playPos = position;
                    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).changeText(arrayList_recent.get(position).getMp3Name(),arrayList_recent.get(position).getCategoryName(),position+1,arrayList_recent.size(),arrayList_recent.get(position).getDuration(),arrayList_recent.get(position).getImageBig(),"home");

                    Constant.context = getActivity();
                    if(position == 0) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PlayerService.class);
                        intent.setAction(PlayerService.ACTION_FIRST_PLAY);
                        getActivity().startService(intent);
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.internet_not_conn), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }));

        return rootView;
    }

    private class LoadLatestNews extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressHUD.show();
            arrayList.clear();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                String json = JsonUtils.getJSONString(strings[0]);

                JSONObject mainJson = new JSONObject(json);
                JSONArray jsonArray = mainJson.getJSONArray(Constant.TAG_ROOT);
                JSONObject objJson = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    objJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = objJson.getString(Constant.TAG_ID);
                    String cid = objJson.getString(Constant.TAG_CAT_ID);
                    String cname = objJson.getString(Constant.TAG_CAT_NAME);
                    String artist = objJson.getString(Constant.TAG_ARTIST);
                    String name = objJson.getString(Constant.TAG_SONG_NAME);
                    String url = objJson.getString(Constant.TAG_MP3_URL);
                    String desc = objJson.getString(Constant.TAG_DESC);
                    String duration = objJson.getString(Constant.TAG_DURATION);
                    String image = objJson.getString(Constant.TAG_THUMB_B).replace(" ","%20");
                    String image_small = objJson.getString(Constant.TAG_THUMB_S).replace(" ","%20");

                    ItemSong objItem = new ItemSong(id,cid,cname,artist,url,image,image_small,name,duration,desc);
                    arrayList.add(objItem);
                }

                return "1";
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "0";
            } catch (Exception ee) {
                ee.printStackTrace();
                return "0";
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            if(s.equals("1")) {
                progressHUD.dismissWithSuccess(getResources().getString(R.string.success));
//                setLatestVariables(0);

                if(Constant.isAppFirst) {
                    if(arrayList.size()>0) {
                        Constant.isAppFirst = false;
                        Constant.arrayList_play.addAll(arrayList);
                        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).changeText(arrayList.get(0).getMp3Name(),arrayList.get(0).getCategoryName(),1,arrayList.size(),arrayList.get(0).getDuration(),arrayList.get(0).getImageBig(),"home");
                        Constant.context = getActivity();
                    }
                }

                viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);

                loadRecent();
//                adapterPagerTrending = new AdapterPagerTrending(getActivity(),Constant.arrayList_trending);
//                viewPager_trending.setAdapter(adapterPagerTrending);

//                adapterTopStories = new AdapterTopStories(getActivity(),Constant.arrayList_topstories);
//                listView_topstories.setAdapter(adapterTopStories);

//                setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listView_topstories);



            } else {
                progressHUD.dismissWithFailure(getResources().getString(R.string.error));
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.server_no_conn), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }
    }

    private void loadRecent() {
        arrayList_recent = dbHelper.loadDataRecent();
        adapterRecent = new AdapterRecent(getActivity(),arrayList_recent);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterRecent);

        if(arrayList_recent.size() == 0) {
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            textView_empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textView_empty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        public ImagePagerAdapter() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return arrayList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view.equals(object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

            View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_home, container, false);
            assert imageLayout != null;
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.imageView_pager_home);
            final ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.loading_home);
            TextView title = (TextView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.textView_pager_home_title);
            TextView cat = (TextView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.textView_pager_home_cat);
            RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.rl_homepager);

            title.setText(arrayList.get(position).getMp3Name());
            cat.setText(arrayList.get(position).getCategoryName());

            Picasso.with(getActivity())
                .load(arrayList.get(position).getImageBig())
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.app_icon)
                .into(imageView, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });

            rl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(JsonUtils.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())) {
                        //showInter();
                        playIntent();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.internet_not_conn), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            container.addView(imageLayout, 0);
            return imageLayout;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View) object);
        }
    }

/*    private void showInter() {
        Constant.adCount = Constant.adCount + 1;
        if(Constant.adCount % Constant.adDisplay == 0) {
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).mInterstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                    playIntent();
                    super.onAdClosed();
                }
            });
            if(((MainActivity)getActivity()).mInterstitial.isLoaded()) {
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).mInterstitial.show();
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).loadInter();
            } else {
                playIntent();
            }
        } else {
            playIntent();
        }
    }
*/
    private void playIntent() {
        Constant.isOnline = true;
        int pos = viewpager.getCurrentItem();
        Constant.arrayList_play.clear();
        Constant.arrayList_play.addAll(arrayList);
        Constant.playPos = pos;
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).changeText(arrayList.get(pos).getMp3Name(),arrayList.get(pos).getCategoryName(),pos+1,arrayList.size(),arrayList.get(pos).getDuration(),arrayList.get(pos).getImageBig(),"home");

        Constant.context = getActivity();
        if(pos == 0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PlayerService.class);
            intent.setAction(PlayerService.ACTION_FIRST_PLAY);
            getActivity().startService(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

I saw another question similar to this, that said to *attach the adapter before running other threads* but I don't believe I have any other threads running in this activity.

Comment: I can't see that you have attached your adapter to your RececlerView by setting `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterRecent); << how about this?

Answer (score 0):

You start a new thread in this line:

```
new LoadLatestNews().execute(Constant.URL_LATEST);
```

and it is executed before control reaches:

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterRecent);
```

This however should not be the problem you have since [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) publishes to the UIThread.

Instead you should set an empty adapter in `onCreateView` and update it with `adapterRecent.notifyDataSetChanged();` once you have loaded your data.

Comment: Thank you so much, i'll try to move that control.

Comment: Error:(195, 9) error: invalid method declaration; return type required

Comment: i have do what you suggest. but the apps become force close, error code said "RecyclerView.Setadapter on null object. 
Nothing works here..

Comment: i have do what you want, but the error message still coming.

Comment: bro? could you help me? :(

Comment: If you want help, you should make a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - reduce your problem to the minimum (kick out everything unnecessary, as few third party libraries as possible), while you provide a complete and verifyable example (including XML, for example). Don't post to pastebin, but edit your question above. Read the stacktrace and give us the line numbers that come with error messages. Also make sure you tell us what you want to do and what you think you need to do.